# merge data from mysql query response from the same day result

Tags: javascript, php

I am using chart.js to create a graph in my website,
I need to set the x-axis labels to the dates of the month, and to add the value of the revenue from each day and display them on the y-axis

**What i tried**

```
data: {
    labels: [
    <?php
    //MYSQL QUERY.........
    //The results are returned in a $response array

    foreach($response as $key => $value){ 
        $date = $value['date'];
        echo '"'.date('M d',strtotime($date)).'", ';
    }
    ?>
    ],
    datasets: [{
                label: "$",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(241, 90, 41, .6)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(241, 90, 41, 1)',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(241, 90, 41, 1)',
                pointBorderColor: 'rgb(13, 22, 64)',
                pointStyle: 'rect',
                fill: 'origin',
                lineTension: 0,
                data: [
                <?php
                //MYSQL QUERY.........
                //The results are returned in a $response array

                foreach($response as $key => $value){ 
                    $date = $value['date'];
                    $revenue = $value['revenue'];
                    echo $total.', ';
                }
                ?>
                ],
            }]
},
```

**current output**

> "Jun 21","Jun 21","Jun 21","Jun 21","Jun 22","Jun 23","Jun 23","Jun
>   24",

**expected output**

show all the dates of the month 1-31 and merge the duplicate data from the query response as below (for example show one jun 21 instead of 4)

> "Jun 21","Jun 22","Jun 23","Jun 24",

Comment: I think this needs to be done in your MySQL query, but you don't show it. This effectively means we cannot help you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i cant do it using the query as its an api call from a third party platform that returns them transaction by transaction

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, then you have to process the response array like this: `$response = array_unique(array_column($response,'date'));`. Do this before the first loop. It gets the 'date' column from the response and makes the dates unique. Note that the order should not be affected, but you need to test that.

Comment: I hope they are real dates, and don't include time as well.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but how would i add up the revenue data day by day  ?

Comment: First: Have you tried what I suggested, and did it work?

Comment: no array_unique does not work as the response returns the date like this `"date": "2017-06-18 22:58:36"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete edit of the code-snippets you provided:

```
data: {
    labels: [
    <?php
    //MYSQL QUERY.........
    //The results are returned in a $response array

    $dates = [];
    foreach($response as $key => $value) { 
        $date    = date('M d',strtotime($value['date']));
        $dates[] = $date;
    }
    $dates = array_unique($dates);
    foreach($dates as $date) { 
        echo '"'.$date.'", ';
    }
    ?>
    ],
    datasets: [{
                label: "$",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(241, 90, 41, .6)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(241, 90, 41, 1)',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(241, 90, 41, 1)',
                pointBorderColor: 'rgb(13, 22, 64)',
                pointStyle: 'rect',
                fill: 'origin',
                lineTension: 0,
                data: [
                <?php
                //MYSQL QUERY.........
                //The results are returned in a $response array

                $totals = [];
                foreach($response as $key => $value) { 
                    $date = date('M d',strtotime($value['date']));
                    $revenue = $value['revenue'];
                    if (isset($totals[$date])) $totals[$date] += $revenue;
                    else $totals[$date] = $revenue;
                }
                foreach($totals as $date => $total) { 
                    echo $total.', ';
                }
                ?>
                ],
            }]
},
```

There is a problem with this code: If there is a date with no revenue at all, and it is missing from the response, then it won't end up in the graph. However you haven't specified exactly what response the API returns, nor what you want in the graph, so I've left it as such.

Comment: the date `labels: []` is not working as expected and the days of the month that are not available in the response form the api call should indicate 0

Comment: response from api call `{
"date": "2017-06-18 22:58:36"
},
{
"date": "2017-06-22 19:01:36"
},`

Comment: I changed the code slightly to take your dates, which also include time, into account.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, this works perfectly but only shows the days where there is revenue, but can it be done to display all the days of the month on x-axis (i guess `label[<? echo date('M')?>1,3,4,5,...31])` and if there is revenue on that day it shows it if not it shows 0 ?

Comment: There are several ways you can do this. A simple method is: 1. Determine the minimum and maximum day you want in your graph. 2. Loop through all those days. 3. If there's no value in `$reponse` for that day add a zero value.

Comment: so lets say, ill put in label [1...31] to keep it simple, how do i loop it in the data set to set the value for each date ? can you help me out in the code pls ?